# How to insert 1000 random int value rows into a column in Sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

i'm a newbie in python3. My homework is create a Sqlite database include 10 tables, each table contains 50 columns, each columns contains 1000 rows, data is randomly generated using Python. I have almost done.

My code :

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('testmydb.db')
cur = conn.cursor()


for table_number in range(1,11):
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE table''' + str(table_number) + '''(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)''')

    listOfColumns = ("column0",)
    for column_number in range(1,49):
        newColumn = ("column" + str(column_number),)
        listOfColumns = listOfColumns + newColumn

    for column_number in listOfColumns:
        cur.execute('''ALTER TABLE table''' + str(table_number) + ''' ADD COLUMN %s TEXT''' % column_number)

conn.commit()    
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Now i want to insert 1000 row into 1 colums but i'm confusing when i wanted create a `for` loop more. Can anyone suggest me ?

Comment: you shouldn't use string concatenation when writing sql in python. you should use placeholders to avoid sql injection attacks. [this](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/insert/) will help you.

Comment: Really? Thank you khuynh, i will fix it. Do you have any suggestions on above problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do what you want (see comments)

```
import sqlite3
import random
conn = sqlite3.connect('testmydb.db')
cur = conn.cursor()


#Only need to do this once
listOfColumns = ("column0",)
bindMarkers = ",?" #ADDED to allow values to be bound will be ?,?,?,?, ........ 49 ?
for column_number in range(1, 49):
    newColumn = ("column" + str(column_number),)
    listOfColumns = listOfColumns + newColumn
    bindMarkers = bindMarkers + ",?"

for table_number in range(1,11):
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table" + str(table_number)) #make it rerunnable
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table''' + str(table_number) + '''(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)''')

    for column_number in listOfColumns:
        cur.execute('''ALTER TABLE table''' + str(table_number) + ''' ADD COLUMN %s TEXT''' % column_number)

    # The INSERT statement note null means that the id will be automatically generated
    insertsql = "INSERT INTO table" + str(table_number) + " VALUES(null" + bindMarkers + ")"
    #print the INSERT SQL (just the once)
    if table_number == 1:
        print(insertsql)

    for row_number in range(1,1001):
        # Generate a list of 49 random values
        listOfRandomValues =[random.randint(1, 999999999999) for i in range(49)]
        cur.execute(insertsql,listOfRandomValues) # insert the row

    # extract the first 5 rows an print each row
    cursor = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table" + str(table_number) + " LIMIT 5")
    result = "row in table table" +  str(table_number) + " Data is "
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)

conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

This will produce output like (first line is the first INSERT statement/SQL) :-

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)



(1, '208968800970', '673486951978', '416011320117', '257739455602', '161014001387', '66915092142', '192394825558', '894946418178', '147479449787', '429768915009', '343072031065', '312483697033', '38240897968', '179592184222', '517690986147', '401721693004', '760956848808', '787028914225', '658523299261', '923606731801', '740090529164', '169600507787', '441903806645', '82302358448', '250921627878', '542116452618', '998918595471', '775548995005', '733089506549', '957054106540', '449321507524', '798501631292', '409382414444', '945602662286', '706232454927', '930118739979', '691405693853', '201175361297', '513975533346', '16690109599', '592944414377', '948709328664', '490207084748', '406188522423', '799744354342', '474761616653', '314527920015', '94102072722', '912028741567')
(2, '172875509043', '126844020427', '423436418690', '973535472434', '171412421537', '693479106176', '909004577995', '920911700813', '605955273811', '325652512054', '94057263900', '45907520985', '64928934172', '301130729226', '103229253943', '114469347031', '551553752113', '626314462779', '22617947251', '997836163264', '585793592332', '620096766798', '565760327235', '348031514661', '871589505728', '58320228377', '179652288652', '977988196994', '742110712624', '201181530463', '816248034687', '22951611374', '723154858722', '289036915539', '997272483698', '61348539011', '977373908399', '668284539899', '55348735729', '263726052214', '662603583920', '790720286573', '487793507420', '883073500835', '519633722649', '383008255347', '30563959610', '617324332661', '89956476106')
(3, '253567041183', '70027774987', '535230659770', '191267720449', '791090949115', '399626615217', '649492276413', '594283985270', '983353743022', '713002984294', '982490173135', '109850128623', '571489216078', '900560015434', '729185220526', '362712800267', '619582132251', '990925729743', '144006421433', '790742578660', '64886161120', '266462916556', '89211644675', '941650491818', '878437527129', '827767387129', '899754797443', '280555144440', '623469334050', '882001652568', '395198811620', '393149546360', '509545198950', '534252806675', '582802496697', '674715538387', '748829323303', '296068248515', '573789396002', '84015250035', '963083904856', '677426863455', '173505995385', '569976297792', '643158854425', '273191627696', '676364784545', '536715691007', '678846958313')
(4, '575055534615', '179094408882', '418242646417', '258767847915', '533305509121', '800410396430', '416643709991', '453093467839', '352906227023', '711478657972', '542560050616', '477511637703', '464619274323', '438591712313', '293891594997', '638717557413', '796607432824', '845617819673', '682479247215', '687662681530', '682910774205', '547150987433', '645097550529', '781225444825', '498491871793', '280308928866', '386747319120', '175187502068', '554032903538', '906897892968', '847200546291', '724824936579', '257524554306', '341479642174', '628478037881', '41911000836', '487139622046', '698641404274', '300203051807', '321147725978', '201308004931', '324554566932', '54668008952', '799888599714', '544776279131', '851164639529', '1118079080', '993554994315', '97774308420')
(5, '263377483252', '535276579958', '434436394255', '235123585872', '886866465625', '83437890933', '546739192349', '832929945092', '889303183895', '517501283515', '386452334064', '437005515113', '567305852696', '254940127493', '158473804439', '714105412308', '887616841407', '873758857265', '59024734698', '495085412255', '757296111012', '438130715784', '661863799528', '370244296694', '559859930401', '409259131854', '72716791778', '900054227569', '897455645761', '254989679831', '46456169823', '597888422562', '581408791663', '191438417130', '468539979785', '998729241595', '596707251066', '731997835957', '432001941801', '351970232680', '602771773558', '793033654396', '205236245465', '547142878108', '973842386021', '742055066627', '455501634405', '130419180039', '870186517783')
(1, '472841964440', '177094420514', '859773622393', '943573354468', '909606787130', '278659426379', '129796913302', '67857238168', '104155180296', '581639712382', '451184580063', '917433785632', '226959780068', '190462507493', '256274613979', '919674630928', '976702823134', '121337013780', '254022515917', '293782992065', '903483153770', '147697931939', '279062893088', '553519369139', '962433270653', '640822114280', '816716757345', '999707836592', '697963179054', '104305203866', '735705858863', '617083342099', '262076004375', '797912340506', '205887749382', '576489282235', '705096989440', '670969562520', '649164826831', '311493582872', '760367591190', '749686855909', '819181100789', '466265188300', '304292298579', '420782152623', '854335337149', '916391611738', '964274785687')
(2, '621325506597', '776006955683', '137683264810', '351906945610', '682429690372', '965366508605', '666337420753', '453325880143', '70778770818', '103682937480', '868216544504', '229703959756', '41004116292', '507097353534', '871910281669', '251530835311', '836500603189', '601460038094', '897559700303', '681312522817', '161143454247', '553960203443', '777460295192', '458302954528', '977754347041', '892360041754', '681995024692', '248485864749', '348381577064', '450879805019', '650777503736', '353872867221', '97506344721', '747237255889', '455629065944', '861413783175', '214743871915', '77511793017', '621196858622', '825422146350', '489409477723', '908004452720', '238639741015', '426722798842', '980323652543', '561628376666', '838205614824', '784039262073', '949055065484')
(3, '736008123891', '923934389646', '546159245294', '429258073881', '583372466354', '50804206500', '273716995212', '733988654121', '788160350686', '749598895287', '551751993459', '916986772574', '622366294456', '687624270621', '185660393899', '329963428664', '928661078668', '875765821125', '754653923243', '151547845857', '248763933358', '636547599095', '87140063802', '267688269107', '224477253917', '641792646340', '59046381016', '103443043545', '485267444040', '387215340714', '268223896307', '480068950182', '225811319773', '492031230630', '502916805016', '514567127425', '178032451267', '750288734257', '825600642728', '641081438590', '207022050440', '902457228778', '115373751089', '348372424350', '768147081429', '715162751738', '210598155420', '196905259558', '873091126544')
(4, '560125266801', '378302831641', '471084702841', '679900688640', '201624340251', '909766550240', '687623074376', '116508086811', '217573740193', '378086229046', '466649195230', '932285473013', '648745964471', '968517127245', '748917121449', '224930472692', '698734544540', '793428186573', '153336974374', '24843476682', '42926459163', '503345524005', '116363947828', '524399560588', '238188045685', '3353134402', '97245283198', '780904780984', '768226492682', '337351478339', '761762114083', '4108216481', '715457129140', '718946387960', '808632491477', '283509135313', '750631442686', '302040053814', '354520401885', '30869550070', '831081853310', '317334330124', '175699898404', '316762996417', '144843539429', '647890863625', '500905345131', '686585819856', '439083530058')
(5, '786320993918', '418227705376', '222672045565', '50994821164', '445050766070', '655740733971', '144925180595', '178456995314', '968483620704', '217344736719', '659133382247', '699130444999', '645737723689', '211418136852', '977174813693', '404005933734', '416012774264', '498694089898', '286235598876', '105048705716', '745323502156', '22320974963', '287621972357', '484051431377', '677832782489', '175141638805', '652237666867', '633826915005', '826792363302', '181964153730', '549735148579', '820006084751', '622355043852', '615716362152', '337022948655', '280970738440', '264064973515', '550249406679', '912858473551', '542805313957', '43397863679', '257720759974', '189160263335', '265086252271', '692156831796', '860245023055', '769544988002', '856033591981', '865669688852')
(1, '29773154022', '105812125224', '923886735040', '494040618517', '406872772654', '964605045362', '483548207268', '222657267987', '728533595865', '427758006630', '250839721516', '246117222632', '625392752778', '372756660516', '276521371279', '677307428516', '434498176501', '757867858941', '568841625163', '315224423736', '939706907834', '567757610656', '977473375050', '476473505693', '921117900131', '344700573908', '350627473109', '569315794206', '780528101292', '957322180230', '952406583209', '435610932961', '463449885730', '174468401098', '916963726643', '193968348451', '297427605119', '481930164885', '685603984144', '543719297225', '612929787721', '475021539217', '176642603133', '74400339089', '95276914071', '808000358479', '79312180687', '502877681225', '659274942719')
..........
```

> i still don't get what is variable bindMarkers and if table_number == 1: print(insertsql)

First the 2nd the line `if table_number == 1: print(insertsql)`

Is just printing out the INSERT statement to show what it looks like. It was just included for that and is not necessary. BUT, it's useful to know what it looks like to explain the ? placeholder and binding values.

So the INSERT statement is along the lines of

```
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES(null,?,? ....... (49 ?'s)
```

- *tablex where x represents 1-10*

First null as per the comment allows SQLite to generate a unique value for the id column.

Each ? is a placeholder and will be replaced by a bound value. This technique prevents SQL injection.

**bindMarkers** is just a string that is generated with 1 ? per column so it's a string of 49 ?'s (easier than typing `VALUES(null,?,?,?,?,? .....)` and also more flexible/adaptable if the column number were to change).

You see that the line `listOfRandomValues =[random.randint(1, 999999999999) for i in range(49)]` creates a List of 49 random values each will be used to replace a single ? (the first value replaces the first ?, the second value replaces the second ? and so on).

This is considered better practice than building a statement along the lines of

```
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES(null,'208968800970', '673486951978', '416011320117', '257739455602', '161014001387', '66915092142', '192394825558', '894946418178', '147479449787', '429768915009', '343072031065', '312483697033', '38240897968', '179592184222', '517690986147', '401721693004', '760956848808', '787028914225', '658523299261', '923606731801', '740090529164', '169600507787', '441903806645', '82302358448', '250921627878', '542116452618', '998918595471', '775548995005', '733089506549', '957054106540', '449321507524', '798501631292', '409382414444', '945602662286', '706232454927', '930118739979', '691405693853', '201175361297', '513975533346', '16690109599', '592944414377', '948709328664', '490207084748', '406188522423', '799744354342', '474761616653', '314527920015', '94102072722', '912028741567')
```

The statement itself is shorter (i.e 1 ? instead of 12 digits) and therefore less likely to cause issues with limits.

Comment: Wow ! Great ! You saved my day. Thanks very much, but i still don't get what is variable `bindMarkers` and `if table_number == 1: print(insertsql)` to do what, it's really necessary?

Comment: @BinhDuong I've edited the answer to explain. If you believe that the answer helped you then please tick it as the answer.